# Reading Lines in Batch File - How To Read Paired Distant Lines

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to making a batch file to store the account names and passwords of thousands of accounts in 32 block intervals.  It will do something different in the first account of every 32 accounts.  I currently have this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@set a=1
@set b=32
@set c=1
@set d=32
@set e=31
@set f=1
@set h=1427
FOR /f "delims=" %%g IN (acct.txt) DO (
 IF !a! EQU !f! (
  echo %%g >> ACCTS!f!-!b!.bat
  @set /a a=!a!+!c!
  ECHO %%g
  @set /a g=!g!+!h!
  ECHO %%g
  @set /a g=!g!-!h!
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO %%g
  echo %%g >> ACCTS!f!-!b!.bat
  @set /a a=!a!+!c!
 )
 IF !a! EQU !b! (
  echo %%g >> ACCTS!f!-!b!.bat
  @set /a b=!b!+!d!
  @set /a f=!f!+!d!
  @set /a a=!a!+!c!
  ECHO %%g
  pause
 )
)
ECHO FINISHED
pause
```

However, the text file that I am reading from contains the passwords 1427 lines away, and I need the username and password to be paired.  Is there a way to read and then write from g and g+1427?  Obviously, the method I tried here did not work.

Regards,
user

Comment: Showing us code and saying that it doesn't work does us no good unless you fully explain the input as well as the desired output. I realize the input file is too big to post in its entirety, but at least post some snippets of what the lines look like. Also describe specifically what is not working in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET count=0
SET distance=5
:: create a temporary file with a dummy line, 
:: then numbered lines from the data file
ECHO 0:dummy >dummy.txt
TYPE acct.txt|FINDSTR /n "$">>dummy.txt
:: Now pair lines
(
FOR /l %%z IN (1,1,%distance%) DO (
 CALL :grabline account %%z
 SET /a skip=%%z+%distance%
 CALL :grabline password !skip!
 SET "account=!account:*:=!"
 SET "password=!password:*:=!"
 ECHO(!account! !password!
)
)>acctpass.txt

del dummy.txt

GOTO :eof
:grabline
FOR /f "skip=%2delims=" %%d IN (dummy.txt) DO SET "%1=%%d"&GOTO :eof
GOTO :eof
```

I've no idea what `"32 block intervals"` are, but here's a routine to pair the lines located at a defined distance. I used a distance of 5 for testing with a file

account1
...
account5
password1
...
password5

(where ... are the missing lines, not `...`)

and got

account1 password1
...
account5 password5

From there, you should be able to make it work. If not, as dbenham says, please be more specific and give examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well explained and missed several details. When this happen, we can *guess* what you are trying to achieve and fill the gaps in any way. For example:

- You want to process all the lines of a text file. However, I am not sure if you want to process just a certain number of lines; for example, until line 1408. Why this number? Because it is the last line of a block of 32 lines before line 1428, that I suppose have not an username, but a password.
- You want to pair each line with the one placed 1427 lines ahead.
- Every 32 lines you want to do "something different", like store the block of 32 lines in a different file.

If the input file is less than 64 MB size, you may load the whole file in an array (memory variables). For example, if the file contains a total of 1408+1427 lines, then each username or password may have up to 64MB/2835 minus the variable name = 23650 characters long approximately! If each username or password have 8 characters and the variable name use 8 characters as average, then your file could have 64MB/16 = 4 MB lines! For this reason, I think this method is a suitable solution to your problem. When the lines are loaded in memory variables, you have direct access to anyone of them.

The Batch file below load the text file in `line` array and then process it in the previously described way.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the file in "line" array
set index=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (acct.txt) do (
   set /A index+=1
   set line[!index!]=%%a
)

rem Process the lines in blocks of 32
set /A numBlocks=1428/32, firstAcct=1

for /L %%b in (1,1,%numBlocks%) do (
   set /A lastAcct=firstAcct+31
   (for /L %%a in (!firstAcct!,1,!lastAcct!) do (
      set /A password=%%a+1427
      for %%p in (!password!) do echo Username: !line[%%a]!  Password: !line[%%p]!
   )) > ACCTS!firstAcct!-!lastAcct!.txt
   set /A firstAcct=lastAcct+1
)
```